# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: VC accordions

Tags: jquery, wordpress, visual-composer

I have a wordpress website where I have setup accordions by the visual composer but at frontend accordions not working and giving this errors in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.fa (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at a.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at getTarget (vc-accordion.min.js?ver=5.5.5:1)
    at Accordion.getTarget (vc-accordion.min.js?ver=5.5.5:1)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (vc-accordion.min.js?ver=5.5.5:1)
    at jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
```

I am unable to track down the cause of issue.
I tried Switching theme, Deactivated all plugins but issue not fixed.
Structure of anchor is sometning like this where I am clicking to open or close the tabs:

```
<a href="#1541001372509-febe2837-9c0b" data-vc-accordion="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta-container"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Oct 30, 2018</span><i class="vc_tta-controls-icon vc_tta-controls-icon-triangle"></i></a>
```

Please suggest me what should I do to track down the issue, many thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are potentially trying to do a find with just `$('#')`.  Combined with the `getTarget` reference, do you have a `data-target="#"` on anything?

Comment: @Taplar I updated my question and pasted html. Its a inbuilt feature of visual composer.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mikado.ticksy.com/ticket/1465312/

Comment: Thankyou @Taplar , the above link solved my problem... Please answer on my question I will accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post it as an answer, as it would be a link only answer.  If you would explain what the issue was and how you fixed it, you can answer your own question, for future readers benefit. @Rango

Comment: Hey @Rango the link doesn't work anymore. How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I found a solution, although I do not know why it worked -
I added to one of the sections of the accordion an ID, and then the accordion went back to work properly, without this error  in the console.
I can see that the value I gave in the ID appears in the section's href attribute, where before there was only the '#' that appeared in error.

Hope this helps you too...